Null Move Pruning Makes my Engine Slower on almost all Positions
I've recently implemented Null Move Pruning into my Chess AI (written in VB.net), but unfortunately it is not actually saving the search any time, in pretty much any position. I was just wondering if there are any apparent flaws in my approach, or implementation, of this NMP algorithm?
I'm currently using R = 3 (but have tried R = 2), and I use MiniMax, rather than NegaMax, in my search algorithm (I could technically migrate to NegaMax, but that would take a while, and I doubt it'd make my engine stronger?). Hopefully that doesn't make things too hard to follow, although I fear that the issue with this algorithm has to do with that structure (as it changes the meaning of Alpha & Beta from ~{best move for me, best move for opponent} to ~{best move for white, best move for black}).
A couple of test positions:

r3k2r/p1ppqpb1/bn2pnp1/3PN3/1p2P3/2N2Q1p/PPPBBPPP/R3K2R w KQkq - (~60% slower with NMP on, although this is mainly for the higher depths (ie: 8+). Lower depths seem to be unaffected).

r1b1kb1r/2pp1ppp/1np1q3/p3P3/2P5/1P6/PB1NQPPP/R3KB1R b KQkq - (roughly 40% slower with NMP, although funnily enough if I enable NMP for only the black pieces, I do see a significant performance increase! This is not the case for the first test position).
I've also experimented with different Alpha-Beta windows, and only using NullMoves if Alpha = Beta - 1. Nothing seems to work.


My code is below (I've only included lines which are essential to this implementation).
The ActNullMove sub: (reversible??)
Sub ActNullMove(Board, EnPassant, ZobristValue)
        'Removes EnPassant Privileges from the hash value.
        If EnPassant <> 0 Then ZobristValue = ZobristValue Xor ZobristHashTable(2, 0, (EnPassant And 56) >> 3, EnPassant And 7)
        'Changes the player to move on the Zobrist Key.
        ZobristValue = ZobristValue Xor HashConstants(0)
    End Sub

And the main search algorithm:
If depth >= 4 AndAlso not PlayerInCheck AndAlso CanTakeNullMove AndAlso PieceInPos Then
    StandPat = Evaluate(Board, MaterialCount, WKPos, BKPos)
    If WhiteTurn Then
        If StandPat >= Beta Then
            ActNullMove(Board, EnPassant, ZobristValue)
            DepthFromRoot += 1
            BestMove = MiniMax(Board, depth - SearchSettings.NullMoveRValue - 1, WhiteTurn=False, EnPassant=0, ZobristValue, Beta - 1, Beta, CanTakeNullMove=False)
            DepthFromRoot -= 1
            ActNullMove(Board, EnPassant, ZobristValue)
            If Beta <= BestMove Then Return Beta
        End If
    Else
        If StandPat <= Alpha Then
            ActNullMove(Board, EnPassant, ZobristValue)
            DepthFromRoot += 1
            BestMove = MiniMax(Board, depth - SearchSettings.NullMoveRValue - 1, WhiteTurn=True, EnPassant=0, ZobristValue, ZobristValue, Alpha, Alpha + 1, CanTakeNullMove=False)
            DepthFromRoot -= 1
            ActNullMove(Board, EnPassant, ZobristValue)
            If BestMove <= Alpha Then Return Alpha
        End If
    End If
End If


sounds like you're missing a negative sign somewhere. I don't know where the exact problem is, but you should really consider using negamax instead. It's much cleaner and is a lot easier to handle once you get used to it. I don't know where the problem is, but I think in the long run you'll save a lot of work and debugging by using negamax instead.
But, here is some sample code from my engine if it helps:
(Note that depth is used to mean depth from root,)
 if allowNull and depth != 0 and (maxSearchDepth - depth) >= 2:  # dont search leaf/frontier nodes, NMP wastes energy here
        if not GetGamePhase(board) < MAX_ENDGAME_PHASE:  # don't null move in potential zugzwang positions
            if not IsCheck(board):
                board[64] = 1 - board[64]  # flip turn flag                  
                epTemp = board[69]
                board[69] = 8  # no ep
                nullMoveScore = -Search(board, maxSearchDepth - R, -beta, -beta + 1, depth + 1, allowNull=False)      
                board[64] = 1 - board[64]  # unflip turn flag
                board[69] = epTemp # reset ep flag
                if nullMoveScore >= beta:
                    return beta

